# Problems with std::function

Tags: c++, function, compiler-errors, std

This is how I have my code setup:

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
    std::function<void()> someFunction;
}
```

AnotherClass.h

```
class AnotherClass
{
public:
    void anotherFunction();
    void yetAnotherFunction();
    SomeClass someClass;
}
```

AnotherClass.cpp

```
void AnotherClass::anotherFunction()
{
    std::cout << "triggerd" << std::endl;
}

void AnotherClass::yetAnotherFunction()
{
    someClass.someFunction = &AnotherClass::anotherFunction; //here
}
```

This resulted in a compile time error: `error C2664: 'std::_Func_class<_Ret>::_Set' : cannot convert parameter 1 from '_Myimpl *' to 'std::_Func_base<_Rx> *'` After some research I found that this is a bug from VS2012 ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096162/stdfunction-not-compiling-in-vs2012)). So I changed the line labeled "here" to `someClass.someFunction = std::mem_fn(&AnotherClass::anotherFunction);` just like the solution says in the link. However, now this results in another compile time error: `error C2562: 'std::_Callable_obj<_Ty>::_ApplyX' : 'void' function returning a value`. So from the research I've found on that error, it means that there is a function declared as void returning a value. This is where I'm stuck because I'm 100% sure I don't have any functions returning a value that shouldn't be plus I didn't get this error before changing the line labeled "here". I not sure if this is another bug in VS2012 but the error does say: `std::_Callable_obj<_Ty>::_ApplyX` which is obviously not my function.

Does anybody have any information on why this is happening and how I can resolve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Your `std::function` has the wrong function type to hold a member function. Either change that, or bind an instance.

Comment: `AnotherClass::anotherFunction` isn't a function. It's not something you can call. Think about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are assigning a non-static member function to a `function` object that expects something returning `void` and taking no arguments. A non-static member function has an implicit first parameter, which in this case would be of type `AnotherClass*`. You need an `AnotherClass` instance to bind to the member function.

In your case, you can bind it to the `this` pointer:

```
void AnotherClass::yetAnotherFunction()
{
    someClass.someFunction = std::bind(&AnotherClass::anotherFunction, this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bind the member-function call `this->anotherFunction()`, then say:

```
somceClass.someFunction = std::bind(&AnotherClass::anotherFunction, this);
```